# Program outputting incorrect answers for even and odd program

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

I need to create a program that gets 6 random integer inputs(3 even, 3 odd; in any order) and then displays the smallest even and odd integer inputted. My code almost does exactly that except if you enter a number such as -6 for the first variable and go all the way to -1 for the last variable, the smallest even is counted as -4 and the smallest odd is -5. What exactly is going wrong that makes this happen?

```
short int a, b, c, d, e, f, smallEven=0, smallOdd=0;


 cout<<"Enter a number: ";          //test a-c: even or odd; is there a small even or small odd; if there is, is new input smaller than old?
cin>>a;
if (a%2==0){
   if (smallEven==0)
      smallEven=d;
   else if (a<smallEven)
        smallEven=a;
}
else if (a%2== 1 || a%2== -1){
     if (smallOdd==0)
        smallOdd=a;
     else if (a<smallOdd)
          smallOdd=a;} 

cout<<"Enter a number: ";
cin>>b;
if (b%2==0){
   if (smallEven==0)
      smallEven=b;
   else if (b<smallEven)
        smallEven=b;
}
else if (b%2==1 || b%2== -1){
     if (smallOdd==0)
        smallOdd=b;
     else if (b<smallOdd)
          smallOdd=b;}

cout<<"Enter a number: ";
cin>>c;
if (c%2==0){
   if (smallEven==0)
      smallEven=c;
   else if (c<smallEven)
        smallEven=c;
}
else if (c%2== 1 || c%2== -1){
     if (smallOdd==0)
        smallOdd=c;
     else if (c<smallOdd)
          smallOdd=c;}


cout<<"Enter a number: ";           //at this point only need to ask if input is even or odd, and if its the smallest
cin>>d;
if (d%2==0){
   if (d<smallEven)
        smallEven=d;
}
else if (d%2== 1 || d%2== -1){
     if (d<smallOdd)
          smallOdd=d;}

 cout<<"Enter a number: ";
cin>>e;
if (e%2==0){
   if (e<smallEven)
        smallEven=e;}
else if (e%2== 1 || e%2== -1){
     if (e<smallOdd)
          smallOdd=e;}

cout<<"Enter a number: ";
cin>>f;
if (f%2==0){
   if (f<smallEven)
        smallEven=f;}
else if (f%2== 1 || f%2== -1){
     if (f<smallOdd)
          smallOdd=f;}
```

Comment: Instead of repeating the same code over and over, create a function that does the repeating code.

Comment: The professor wants us only using what we learned in class which means no functions and no loops

Comment: You should learn about using a debugger. It will allow you to pause the program execution and do stuff like look at the values stored in variables. Search up a tutorial or get some sort of C++ book. This is not the place to have someone debug your program for you.

Comment: @edmonda7 You're victim of a _YAIT_.

Comment: Or you can insert print statements in the middle of your program to print out the values of variables if you have not got to the level of debuggers yet.

Comment: What? No functions? What do you think `int main` is? Or what `cin>>n` is? This are all functions. Learning C++ without functions is like learning to swim in the air.

Comment: You have a built-in logic error... suppose your 3 even numbers entered are: 4  0  6 ... what would your lowest "even" number be..??  Your logic says it would be 6... the reason is you are using the value of "smallEven" as an indicator showing you've had input before...  The same goes for "odd"...

Comment: @Pablo yes but he likely hasn't learned about them yet, he can use pre built ones just not define his own

Comment: @Mitchel0022 I know it's not the OP fault, I think that is incredibly wrong to teach programming without introducing functions. No wonder that some beginner write code as if they have been working with MS Basic of the DOS era.

Comment: @TonyB Sorry, forgot to mention that we're supposed to assume 0 will not be entered as an input

Comment: @Pablo, I was one of those BASIC programmers even *before* that, and I can tell you that we actually *used* `GOSUB` a lot. Even in the earliest assembler days (z80, 6809, 1802), we knew about `call/jsr/sep`, etc. Structured programming has been around for quite a while :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo `GOSUB` that brings back memories. I had back then no clue what that was, so I never used it. I had once 3 line that I repeated 100 times in the code. But back then there was no internet and all I got was the help menu from qbasic...

Answer (score 0):

```
void smallest(int* even, int* odd, int n){
        if(n%2 == 0 && n < *even) *even = n;
        else if(abs(n%2) == 1 && n < *odd) *odd = n;
}
```

then you could do something like this

```
int n, even, odd;

while(cin >> n){
 smallest(&even, &odd, n); 
}
```

if you need to do it this way for an assignment the logic seems right but check the variables very carefully. I see some typos in the first block.

Comment: When "smallest()" is called, Suppose "*even" == -10  and "*odd" == zero and "n" == -6 ... what would the value of "*odd" be after the call..??  Your first "if" statement has two conditions in it, so your second "if" needs to test whether "n" is "odd"...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with lots of repeated code is that you often make cut'n'paste errors while copying it. That's evident in your first section if that you `cin >> **a**` but then `if (smallEven==0) smallEven=**d**`.

The ideal way to do this would be to break it up into functions but, since you state you're not allowed to do that due to course restrictions, you can still greatly clean up your code by realising you don't *need* a lot of variables.

```
int num, smallEven, smallOdd, countEven = 0, countOdd = 0;

while ((countEven < 3) && (countOdd < 3)) {
    cin >> num;

    // Select even or odd.

    if ((num % 2) == 0) {
        // Check allowed.

        if (countEven == 3) {
            cout << "No more even numbers allowed\n";
            continue;
        }

        // Store if first or lesser, add to count.

        if (countEven == 0) {
            smallEven = num;
        } else {
            if (num < smallEven) {
                smallEven = num;
            }
        }
        countEven++;
    } else {
        // Check allowed.

        if (countOdd == 3) {
            cout << "No more odd numbers allowed\n";
            continue;
        }

        // Store if first or lesser, add to count.

        if (countOdd == 0) {
            smallOdd = num;
        } else {
            if (num < smallOdd) {
                smallOdd = num;
            }
        }
        countOdd++;
    }
```

---

*With* functions, this becomes even easier:

```
void apply(const char *type, const int num, int &count, int &small) {
    if (count == 3) {
        cout << "No more " << type << " numbers allowed\n";
        return;
    }

    // Store if first or lesser.

    if (count == 0) {
        small = num;
    } else {
        if (num < small) {
            small = num;
        }
    }
    count++;
}

:

int num, smallEven, smallOdd, countEven = 0, countOdd = 0;

while ((countEven < 3) && (countOdd < 3)) {
    cin >> num;

    // Select even or odd.

    if ((num % 2) == 0)
        apply("even", num, countEven, smallEven);
    else
        apply("odd", num, countOdd, smallOdd);
}
```